# UIImagePicker freezes

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm able to call the modal view controller for the image picker, pick the image, and crop it, but when I tap 'done' it doesn't do anything, it just hangs with the done button grayed out. 
There are no errors, but the function is called.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imgPicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
userImage.image = img;
uploadButton.hidden = NO;
[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
NSLog(@"called");
}

- (IBAction)getImage:(id)sender {
[self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Does this bug happen every time?

Comment: @golergka It's not a bug, by calling `[picker parentViewController]` you would expect `self`, as seen in @Rayfleck's answer. This is because the parent view controller of `picker` is the same controller that presented it in `getImage:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
 [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

with:

```
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```